# How can I generate a copy of SVN-versioned files without going through the repo?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

My code is versioned using SVN with TortoiseSVN on Windows.

My lint-like tool protests that I got some things wrong. But it's a very picky tool. The many non-versioned helpful files and notes that I keep inside my code base trip it. It complains early and exits. Hence I need to commit and checkout cleanly elsewhere just to be able to do each of the iterations needed to clean my code. Needless to say, I don't want to generate many events in the repo while I'm iterating.

Is there a way through (Tortoise)SVN to generate a copy of the presently versioned files in a separate directory, *without going through the repo*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can drag with the secondary mouse (aka "right") button and select "SVN Export versioned items here" (or maybe "SVN Export changed items here"):

[image: Export here]

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following two steps:

1. Copy the complete checked-out SVN directory to a new location, including the hidden .svn subdirectory/subdirectories.
2. Open the copied version in the Windows Explorer and right-click on working copy folder, while holding the shift-key down and choose "delete unversioned items". Alternatively you can execute in the command shell `svn cleanup . --remove-unversioned`